# After MYSQL upgrade from 5.7.18 to 8.0.17 information_schema db size is 0 Byte

Tags: mysql-8.0

After MYSQL upgrade from 5.7.18  to  8.0.17  information_schema db size is 0 Byte.But if I execute select query on information_schema db tables it is showing records.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading MySQL user schemas and the sys schemas with root user like as shown below then restart MySQL DB:

```
    prior to 8.0.16 : mysql_upgrade -u root –p

    from 8.0.16 on-words:  mysqld --upgrade=MINIMAL
```